# Re-arranging date to mm/dd/yyyy and skipping empty cells in ArcMap using ArcPy cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, datetime

I'm trying to get my code to re-arrange existing dates in the cell to mm/dd/yyyy and skip empty cells. I thought by putting if None: continue would work but it's not.

Any tips?

Here is my code and the result:

```
##location of your oilspills file
arcpy.env.workspace = r's:\User\Lab1'

##use an update cursor to update the values
updateCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor('testfile (3).shp')




findEmpy = row.RPT_DTE
if findEmpty == None:
    findEmpty = '0' + str(row.RPT_DTE)
print findEmpty

#updateCursor.updateRow(row)


oldDate = row.RPT_DTE
if len(oldDate) > 0:
    newDate = oldDate.split("/")
    year = '19' + str(newDate[0])
    month = newDate[1]
    day = newDate[2]
    row.RPT_DTE = month + '/' + day + '/' + year
    print month + '/' + day + '/' + year

#updateCursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not include code as an image. Instead, include it as ASCII text, formatted in a code bock (`{}`), so it is legible and available to those who would help you without retyping.

Answer (score 2):

Use datetime module. I am assuming your field is of text type.

```
from datetime import datetime
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass' #change
textfield = r'somefieldname' #change

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,textfield) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0]: #This will be true if row is not none or empty string
            d = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%y/%m/%d')
            d2 = datetime.strftime(d,'%m/%d/%Y')
            row[0] = d2
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

See [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused of what should be on the with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor line. I tried putting... with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(updateCursor, row.RPT_DTE) as cursor: but i get RuntimeError: 'in_table' is not a table or a featureclass. I edited my code to show the beginning part of my code with importing the file

Comment: You should only change fc and texfield  lines to match your data

Answer (score 1):

If your RPT_DTE column is of type "Date", you can use the datetime module to work more cleanly with its values.  You don't show your cursor call, but if you use the Data Access module you can query out the blank values with a where_clause, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('Name of Layer', 'RPT_DTE', where_clause="RPT_DTE IS NOT NULL") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        date = datetime.strftime(row[0], '%y/%m/%d')
        print date
        newdate = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
        row[0] = newdate
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

If the column is a string type (you can check by right clicking and seeing properties in the attribute table), you can update with the following.  I think the issue is that your call to update the cursor is outside the loop. Also, the value might be equal to '', instead of None.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('Name of Layer', 'RPT_DTE', where_clause="RPT_DTE IS NOT NULL") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] is None or row[0] == '':
            continue
        else:
            y, m, d = row[0].split('/')
            newdate = m + '/' + d + '/' + '19' + y
            row[0] = newdate
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Sorry i'm pretty new to python and arcmap. Where did the Name of Layer come from? I assume I have to replace that with something within the file?

Comment: Yeah, replace that with the name of the data source as it's spelled in the table of contents (where you check it on/off for display)